# 'ml' is not recognized

Tags: windows, visual-studio, nmake

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community installed on Win10 64-bit. Using the `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` shell, I cannot find the MASM executable, `ml`. I thought it was installed with VS. I found the issue when running an `nmake` script as part of the OpenSSL build process for Windows.

```
        ml /nologo /Cp /coff /c /Cx /Zi /Fotmp32dll\x86cpuid.obj tmp32dll\x86cpuid.asm
'ml' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'ml' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Here is my `%PATH%`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Mike\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda2;C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Mike\bin
```

Is MASM included with VS 2015 Community, or is it a separate installable? This is the first time I've ever had to use MASM, so I'm learning a ton about the Windows build tools.

Comment: The 64-bit version of MASM is ml64.exe

Comment: That's what I was reading, shouldn't both exist?

Comment: Well, sure, but you configured the command prompt to use x64 tools so the PATH can only find the one stored in the vc/bin/amd64 subdirectory, not the 32-bit version in vc/bin

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks!